# C# Programming test problems

Tags: c#

I have just completed a C# practice test and have got some answers wrong, but I cannot get hold of my lecturer.

One of the questions that I didn't understand was *"Which of the following is a common exception to the principle of naming variables with whole words?"* The suggested answers are:

1. `f`
2. `i`
3. `l`
4. `b`

Why is the answer `i`?

Another question I don't understand is _*"For which of the following lines of code will the following line be `{` the least often?"*. I didn't really understand this question because of the way it was written. The suggested answers are:

1. `for (int i =0; i < myArray.Length; i++)`
2. `do`
3. `if (foundMatch)`
4. `}`

The answer was `}`.

Comment: 1. Because `i` is a short-hand convention for an index. 2. How many times do you see code that goes `} {`?

Comment: format the code in a better way please

Comment: 2. Combine each possible answer with `{` -- the last answer `} {` looks like a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

1. In C#, `for` loops are very common.  When writing a `for` loop you need an index variable.  By convention, the variable `i` is often used rather than the full word `index`.  It is used so often, that most people understand that `i` is the loop index variable without having to think about it.  There is no such convention (that I'm aware of anyway) for the other suggested variables, `f`, `l` and `b`.  You would be better off spelling out what these variables represent in the code so that people understand it.

   Therefore the answer is `i`.
2. All of the statements `for`, `do` and `if` require a code block to follow them.  The code block could either be a bare, single statement (less common) or a group of one or more statements surrounded by braces `{` and `}` (very common).

   For example:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
   {
       ...
   }

   do
   {
       ...
   } while (!done);

   if (foundMatch)
   {
      ...
   }
   ```

   In contrast, the end of a code block `}` is almost never followed immediately by the start of another code block `{`.  In other words, you won't see this in the code:

   ```
   if (foundMatch)
   {
       ...
   }
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

   Therefore, the answer is `}`.